# I need help in adding columns in an abundance df by plot

Tags: r, aggregate

I have an abundance df with 63 species in the columns and a column with the plots from 1 to 6. The plot repeats 9 times because it represents the 9 subplots I have. With the first 18 (2 plots) rows and first 3 columns it looks like this:

```
> taxa_ab
    plot Sp1 Sp2
1   1    0   0
2   1    1   1             
3   1    0   0               
4   1    0   0               
5   1    0   0               
6   1    0   3               
7   1    0   0               
8   1    0   0               
9   1    0   4               
10  2    4   0               
11  2    0   0               
12  2    0   2               
13  2    0   0               
14  2    0   0               
15  2    0   0
16  2    0   2               
17  2    0   0               
18  2    0   0
```

I want to sum the species by plot so the plot becomes the row name and it looks like this:

```
> ab_new
    Sp1 Sp2
1   1   8
2   4   4
```

I tried to use the aggregate function but I haven't understood how to use it.

```
ab_new <- taxa.ab[,-2] %>%
        aggregate(., by = plot, FUN = "sum")
```

Also my species abundance are integers and I can't seem to convert them to numeric without loosing the structure of the data frame by unlisting the columns.

```
> str(taxa_ab)
'data.frame':   54 obs. of  64 variables:
 $ plot     : chr  "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
 $ Sp1      : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Sp2      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Sp3      : int  0 0 0 1 0 0 1 2 1 1 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Specifically, with the function you were already working on:

To use `aggregate` the way you want, `by` should be a list of the same size of the dataset, not just the name of the variable. That is why I'm putting `taxa.ab[1]`. This way I only get the first column (i.e., plot).

And, you want to input the whole data without the grouping var, that is why I put `taxa.ab[-1]`

### Solution

```
ab_new <- taxa.ab[-1] %>%
  aggregate(., by = taxa.ab[1], FUN = "sum")
```

### Output

```
#   plot Sp1 Sp2
# 1    1   1   8
# 2    2   4   4
```

Answer (score 2):

## Base R solution

With `aggregate` the pipe operator is doing more harm than good. When using the formula interface the dot `.` has a special meaning, it means *"all variables not yet in the formula"*. And since the dot also has a special meaning in `magrittr`'s pipes, there will be a conflict. So, use the (in this case) simpler formula interface.

```r
aggregate(. ~ plot, taxa_ab, sum)
#>   plot Sp1 Sp2
#> 1    1   1   8
#> 2    2   4   4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

And the result is all numeric, there's no structure loss problem.

```r
agg <- aggregate(. ~ plot, taxa_ab, sum)
str(agg)
#> 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ plot: int  1 2
#>  $ Sp1 : int  1 4
#>  $ Sp2 : int  8 4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## `dplyr` solution

Just group and summarise.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(dplyr)
)

taxa_ab %>%
  group_by(plot) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with('Sp'), sum))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>    plot   Sp1   Sp2
#>   <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1     8
#> 2     2     4     4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Data

```r
taxa_ab<-'
plot Sp1 Sp2
1   1    0   0
2   1    1   1             
3   1    0   0               
4   1    0   0               
5   1    0   0               
6   1    0   3               
7   1    0   0               
8   1    0   0               
9   1    0   4               
10  2    4   0               
11  2    0   0               
12  2    0   2               
13  2    0   0               
14  2    0   0               
15  2    0   0
16  2    0   2               
17  2    0   0               
18  2    0   0          
'
taxa_ab <- read.table(textConnection(taxa_ab), header = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I think `group_by` and `summarize` are the functions that you are looking for.

`group_by(plot)` will group all of the rows in your data frame by the `plot` variable, and then you can use the `summarize` function to specify how to treat those grouped rows.

Based on your description, I think your code would look something like

```
df = df %>%
   group_by(plot) %>%
   summarize(Sp1 = sum(Sp1),
             Sp2 = sum(Sp2))
```